# Screen to world coordinates matrix

Tags: matrix, graphics, 3d, linear-algebra

I am trying to get a transformation matrix that would convert screen coordinates to world coordinates. I have a calibration process in which I can find an 8-sided in screen (the world dimensions of the die I know), and I can find the corners of the die. I've never been stellar at linear algebra, but I can plow my way through. I just don't know where to begin. I've been searching for unprojecting theories, but nothing that matches what I have.

Is this even possible? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it's possible.  Usually, mapping 3D coordinates to 2D screen coordinates involves assuming that the viewer is looking at the 3D world through a [frustum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viewing_frustum).  Imagine a line going straight down the center of the frustum, through the center of the "eye".  Any point on that line would map to the screen coordinate at the center of the screen.  So, if you have the 2D screen coordinate of the center of the screen, you couldn't know which point on that line is the 3D coordinate.

Perhaps if you know more information about the object that you're looking at (e.g., if it's an 8-sided die of a known size and you have the positions of some corners), you can use that information to determine which point on the line is correct.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I do mean that - I have a die and I know it's size, and I know how it's sitting on the table. I think I kind of get what you're saying. Do you care to elaborate knowing that we do know the size of the die? Thanks!